# Get first property of an object that matches the condition

Tags: javascript, object

So I have a structure like that:

```
Foo: {
    A: Array[0],
    B: Array[0],
    C: Array[1]
}
```

where `[X]` is length of the array, but `Foo` is an object, not an Array, therefore I can't use Array method on it.

How do I get first element (letter in this case) which has `length > 0` ?

```
for (let letter in Foo) {
    if (letter.length > 0) {
        let match = letter;
    }
}
```

I tried something like this (this is simplified version), but it just returns all properties of `Foo`.

Comment: There is no concept of "first" in an object, the properties are not ordered. Also, *let* is block scoped so you will have difficultly returning *match* from outside the block.

Comment: @RobG condition is supposed to return a set of Arrays which match the criteria. I just want to pick the 1st one out of this set. It's not realistic?

Comment: You can do that, but the value returned may be different in different hosts so the result is not reliable.

Comment: Related to @RobG's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/4475267

Comment: @knitevision: If you want to pick *any* of that set it's ok - but don't expect to get the same result every time you run this. As Rob said, there is no "1st one" in an unordered set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m glad you’re using ES6. In this case you can use `Object.keys` to get an array of all the object’s keys and `Array.prototype.find` to find the first element with a specific property:

```
var obj = {
  a: [],
  b: [],
  c: [
    2,
    3
  ],
  d: [],
  e: [
    1
  ]
};

Object.keys(obj).find(a => obj[a].length > 0); // The letter "c" which contains the first non-empty array.

obj[Object.keys(obj).find(a => obj[a].length > 0)]; // Array [2, 3] itself
```

Note that there’s no consistent “first” element in an object across implementations.